# Compare two Memo lines and delete unmatched lines from both Memo Delphi

Tags: process

I am new for Delphi 10.02

I have two Memo, Memo1 and Memo2 , both filled with lines
How can I compare Memo1 lines with Memo2 lines and delete the uncompared lines from Memo2

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is "Delphi"? Do you mean the [programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(software))? What is a "Memo"? Can you provide example input and desired output?

Comment: Your question might better fit on stackoverflow.com with tag `delphi`. I doubt that the tag `process` is related to your problem. (Maybe `text-processing`?) You should show your (incomplete) code, example input and expected output. If it is not obvious from your code, describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: This belongs on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).  Please delete it from here and post it there.  I could answer it, but my answer will probably get downvotes as will your question  :-)